How to say "id est" or to explain the meaning of a word?
I am currently writing an academic paper on localization and have to explain what some of the terms mean. I am having trouble to understand how to find a good translation to "id est" in Japanese.
This is an example:
"たまには、CATツール、すなわち翻訳支援ツールも付いている。" (What I meant: "Sometimes, CAT Tools, i.e. tools to support translation, are also included.")
Is すなわち actually the appropriate word to use in this case?

This is not what you asked but たまには doesn't sound academic. You might want to change it to 時には.

Thank you, I will.

In general, "i.e." is equivalent to すなわち or つまり as this dictionary entry suggests, but in the given sentence, I think simply parenthesizing would be most natural.

CATツール(翻訳支援ツール)が含まれることもある。

